# Flutter iOS only some video URL's are playing in video player and some fail to initialize

Tags: ios, flutter, video-player

I've been trying to play videos from server in my Flutter iOS app. But They won't initialize. Random video url's from online work fine but videos from my server won't play. Is any special encoding required for iOS to play videos?

I have added this in my info.plist

```
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Urls that work:
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4

URL's that don't work:
https://learningoxygen.com/joy_content/CB Sales Video- English-low-res.mp4
https://learningoxygen.com/joy_content/C.fruit 30 sec.mp4

All these videos work flawlessly in android. issue is with iOS
Please help me out. Thanks.

Here's my code

```
//import 'package:flick_video_player/flick_video_player.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class TestVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestVideoState createState() => _TestVideoState();
}

class _TestVideoState extends State<TestVideo> {
  //FlickManager flickManager;
  bool _isVideoLoading = true;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    init();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: _isVideoLoading == false
          ? Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
              child: Chewie(
                controller: _chewieController,
              ))
          : Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
    );
  }

  void init() async {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://learningoxygen.com/joy_content/CB Sales Video- English-low-res.mp4');

    await _videoPlayerController.initialize().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        print("DONEEE");
        _isVideoLoading = false;
      });
    });

    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Because those two URL have spaces between

Comment: nope, then it shouldn't work on android either.
https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4
This is not working

Comment: have you checked if both, video and audio codecs are compatible?

Comment: you also need to make sure you have CORS enabled to know your videos can be fetch and served without restrictions

Comment: Thank you for your response. CORS might be the problem. I'll check it and update

Comment: Spaces does matter. I tested with a local file, and as I remove the space in the filename it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to replicate the issue in iPhone simulator:

[image]

It seems that this is a known issue, check [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81672).

Although this ticket is already closed, there is an [existing open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56665) related to this.

As mentioned, it is working normally in Android.

[image]