# How to play a Video in flutter using network link

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, video-player

I have a video link and I want to play video in flutter how can I play?

I try using videoplayer plugin but its not work with this url -

"http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"

but I can play with this url why?

"https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4"

Comment: Try with https://pub.dev/packages/pod_player pod_player package

Comment: similar question answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67415863/flutter-ios-only-some-video-urls-are-playing-in-video-player-and-some-fail-to-i?rq=2

Comment: Please share your code for better understanding. Also, please mention on which os you are facing the issue and also in which build mode you are running the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is in Url in this URL
you are using **https**

> "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4"

but in this URL you are using **http** which causing error

> http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4

Error:

```
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$CleartextNotPermittedException: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted.
```

Solution:

Just replace the **http** to **https**

Answer (score -1):

#### The issue you're coming accross is likely due to the specific video URL you're using.

- In fact, videos URLs may have different formats or codecs, which can impact their compatibility with different flutter video players or plugins.
- The second video is more likely to be encoded using a format or codec that is compatible with the video player plugin you're using, hence why it works.
- So next steps will be investigating and see if the plugin you're using supports the format or codec of the particular video that you want to play
- You can find a list of most popular flutter video plugins [here](https://fluttergems.dev/video/) by the way

###### Also, the problem might be coming from the fact that the first video is hosted on a http domain name, not https. Try another http video and see how it goes.

#### Happy coding